# isdlg=1 does nothing, or causes error?

Tags: sharepoint-online, application-pages

I'm trying to display a SharePoint Online page "bare" with no side navigation, ribbons, or any other SP decorations. I don't want my visitors to have to worry about SP at all--to them it's just a web page.

I found the idslg=1 parameter. Adding that to my pages (as opposed to built-in views) has one of two effects: none at all (the page looks exactly the same), or the error, "Sorry, something went wrong An unexpected error has occurred." (Are there expected errors?)

Does isdlg not work on user-defined pages? Or is there some trick I haven't figured out? Thanks.

Comment: Review your URL if the link has "#" symbol before isDlg=1 in this case the page will ignore isdlg parameter,also check if you add "&" symbol before the parameter.

Comment: The URL fits the conditions you mention, but thanks, myomyo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works with list and library pages. It generally will not work with home or custom pages.
With "Modern UI" lists it switches back to "Classic UI" style pages with ribbons.

Best guess... support for it will disappear in SharePoint Online.

Does your page have SharePoint content (web parts, etc) or could it be replaced with an basic HTML page?

Comment: The pages have web parts. In principle I could remake them with just HTML, i guess, but that would presumably make incorporating (e.g.) items from a Library harder. Thanks.